# Ionic: Can't bind to 'ngIf' since it isn't a known property of 'div'

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I know this is a very common issue that has been asked a million of times but after checking lots of forums, I still can't make it work...
The solution that is always provided is to add the "CommonModule" and "BrowserModule" but I got those in my files and nothing changes.
The weird thing is that my other file that uses *ngIf aswell works..

Here is my code :

statistics.page.html

```html
    <ion-content [fullscreen]="true">
    
      <div class="main_block">
        <p class="title">Global Statistics</p>
        <div *ngIf="testsInitialized == false" class="figures_block">
          <div class="figures_subblock">
            <p class="text">You took</p>
            <p class="figure">{{testsAmount}}</p>
            <p class="text">tests in total</p>
          </div>
        </div>
    
        <div *ngIf="testsInitialized" class="figures_block">
          <div class="figures_subblock">
            <p class="text">You took</p>
            <p class="figure">{{testsAmount}}</p>
            <p class="text">tests in total</p>
          </div>
          <div class="figures_subblock">
            <p class="text">Average score of</p>
            <p class="figure">{{testsAverage}}/5</p>
            <p class="text">for all the tests</p>
          </div>
        </div>
          <p class="title">Wall of shame</p>
          <div class="charac_block_container" *ngIf="shameIsOn">
            <div class="pepepoint_div_left">
              <img src="../../assets/img/pepePoint.png">
            </div>
            <div class="charac_block">
              <div class="block_row" *ngIf="phoneticHiraganaMistakesTable">
                <div class="charac_subblock">
                  <p class="text">Hiragana phonetic</p>
                  <p class="charac">{{phoneticHiraganaMistakesTable}}</p>
                </div>
                <div class="counter">
                  <p class="figure">x{{phoneticHiraganaMistakesAmount}}</p>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="block_row" *ngIf="wordHiraganaMistakesTable">
                <div class="charac_subblock">
                  <p class="text">Hiragana word</p>
                  <p class="charac">{{wordHiraganaMistakesTable}}</p>
                </div>
                <div class="counter">
                  <p class="figure">x{{wordHiraganaMistakesAmount}}</p>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="block_row" *ngIf="phoneticKatakanaMistakesTable">
                <div class="charac_subblock">
                  <p class="text">Hiragana phonetic</p>
                  <p class="charac">{{phoneticKatakanaMistakesTable}}</p>
                </div>
                <div class="counter">
                  <p class="figure">x{{phoneticKatakanaMistakesAmount}}</p>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="block_row" *ngIf="wordKatakanaMistakesTable">
                <div class="charac_subblock">
                  <p class="text">Hiragana word</p>
                  <p class="charac">{{wordKatakanaMistakesTable}}</p>
                </div>
                <div class="counter">
                  <p class="figure">x{{wordKatakanaMistakesAmount}}</p>
                </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="pepepoint_div_right">
            <img src="../../assets/img/pepePoint.png">
          </div>
        </div>
    
        <div class="charac_block_container" *ngIf="!shameIsOn">
          <div class="charac_block">
            <div class="block_row">
              <div class="charac_subblock">
                <p class="charac">No shame yet...</p>
              </div>
              
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
    
        <ion-button (click)="clearStatsAlertConfirm()">Clear All</ion-button>
    
      </div>
    
      Coming soon...
    
      
      
    
    
    </ion-content>
```

statistics.page.ts

```js
    import { StatsService } from './../service/stats.service';
    import { AlertController, ModalController } from '@ionic/angular';
    import { SettingsPage } from '../settings/settings.page';
    import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
    
    @Component({
      selector: 'app-statistics',
      templateUrl: './statistics.page.html',
      styleUrls: ['./statistics.page.scss'],
    })
    export class StatisticsPage implements OnInit {
    
      testsAmount: any = 0;
      testsAverage: any ="-";
      testsInitialized: boolean = false;
      phoneticHiraganaMistakesTable: string;
      wordHiraganaMistakesTable: string;
      phoneticKatakanaMistakesTable: string;
      wordKatakanaMistakesTable: string;
      phoneticHiraganaMistakesAmount: number;
      wordHiraganaMistakesAmount: number;
      phoneticKatakanaMistakesAmount: number;
      wordKatakanaMistakesAmount: number;
      isPhoneticHiraganaMistakesTable: boolean;
      isWordHiraganaMistakesTable: boolean;
      isPhoneticKatakanaMistakesTable: boolean;
      isWordKatakanaMistakesTable: boolean;
      shameIsOn: boolean;
    
      constructor(public statsService: StatsService, public alertController: AlertController, private modalController: ModalController) {}
    
      removeAll(){
        this.statsService.clearAll();
      }
    
      async ngOnInit() {
    // some code here
        }

}
```

statistics.module.ts

```js
    import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
    import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
    import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
    import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
    
    import { IonicModule } from '@ionic/angular';
    
    import { StatisticsPageRoutingModule } from './statistics-routing.module';
    
    import { StatisticsPage } from './statistics.page';
    
    @NgModule({
      imports: [
        CommonModule,
        BrowserModule,
        FormsModule,
        IonicModule,
        StatisticsPageRoutingModule
      ],
      declarations: [StatisticsPage]
    })
    export class StatisticsPageModule {}
```

app.module.ts

```js
    import { StatsService } from './service/stats.service';
    import { NativeAudio } from '@ionic-native/native-audio/ngx';
    import { Injectable, NgModule} from '@angular/core';
    import { BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser';
    import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
    import { RouteReuseStrategy } from '@angular/router';
    
    import { IonicModule, IonicRouteStrategy } from '@ionic/angular';
    
    import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
    import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
    
    import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
    
    import { SuperTabsModule } from '@ionic-super-tabs/angular';
    import { IonicStorageModule } from '@ionic/storage-angular';
    import * as CordovaSQLiteDriver from 'localforage-cordovasqlitedriver';
    import { Drivers } from '@ionic/storage';
    
    @NgModule({
      declarations: [AppComponent],
      entryComponents: [],
      imports: [BrowserModule,
        CommonModule,
        IonicModule.forRoot(),
        AppRoutingModule,
        HttpClientModule,
        SuperTabsModule.forRoot(),
        IonicStorageModule.forRoot({
          name: 'statsDB',
          driverOrder: [CordovaSQLiteDriver._driver, Drivers.IndexedDB]
        }),],
      providers: [
        { provide: RouteReuseStrategy, useClass: IonicRouteStrategy },
        {provide: NativeAudio, useClass: NativeAudio},
        StatsService,
      ],
      bootstrap: [AppComponent],
    })
    export class AppModule {}
```

I tried restarting the IDE aswell with no luck

Comment: Show the exact error message output by the tools

Comment: core.js:10101 NG0303: Can't bind to 'ngIf' since it isn't a known property of 'div'.

Comment: StatisticsPageModule is missing from your app module. Please import `StatisticsPageModule` in your app module.

Comment: It seems like it fixed the issue but I don't understand why I need to import the module of a specific page when all other pages work well without that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found the answer and this is either very dumb or my understanding of Angular is lacking..
So it appeared that I didn't have the route of the statistics configured in the `app-routing.module.ts` which wasn't a problem as I used the super-tab module to display my page. When I added the route for the statistics page, it suddenly fixed the *ngIf error.
My guess is that it needs to preload the page to link some modules ? (There is the import of the "PreloadAllModules" in the route module)

Answer (score 2):

As @Mir entafaz Ali already answered as comment, you have to import the module, to be able to use the component. For what I can see in your code, you're using a routing module. Meaning that you're lazy loading the pages. *What you should do*.

In the `app-routing.module.ts` you should be loading the tabs. like follow

```js
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    loadChildren: () => import('./tabs/tabs.module').then((m) => m.TabsPageModule),
  },
]
```

And then, in your `tabs-routing.module.ts` you should be importing the `StatisticsPageModule` like this.

```js
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'tabs',
    component: TabsPage,
    children: [
      {
        path: 'statistics',
        loadChildren: () => import('route/to/statistics.module').then((m) => m.StatisticsPageModule)
      },
    ]
  }
]
```

Do note, `StatisticsPageModule` should be imported only once, and it should be imported in the `tabs-routing.module.ts`. Remove it from everywhere else.

Also, your `StatisticsPageModule` the `BrowserModule` which should be imported **only once** in your application, and in the `app.module.ts`. So please do remove this one from the `StatisticsPageModule` this should fix the error.

*This should also give an answer this question*

> I don't understand why I need to import the module of a specific page when all other pages work well without that

Comment: I added the BrowserModule in the StatisticsPageModule when I was still trying to fix the issue by myself. I just tried removing it while removing the import of the StatisticsPageModule in the app.module.ts. Unfortunately it brings back the *ngIf error.
Considering I have another page that uses *ngIf aswell and has a similar configuration that doesn't give me an error, i'm really confused. Maybe that's a bug ? Because i'm pretty sure it started giving me the error after I updated some packages.

Comment: @LittleOne Remove `BrowserModule` every where but let it in the `app.module.ts`. Import the `StatisticsPageModule` in your `app.module.ts`. I'm pretty sure angular does not have a bug on this one, because you wouldn't be the first one to see this. What is the angular version you use?

Comment: I did try this solution and it was working fine but I posted another solution (last post) yesterday explaining how I solved it. It was not an Angular bug indeed..

Comment: @LittleOne I did update my answer to give you more information about your error. Does it help?

Comment: Thx for the precisions, I understand that I shouldn't duplicate those modules. Regarding the routing configuration, super-tabs work differently than normal ion tabs, you don't need to nest routes because you already nest the different routes in the html when adding each page in the `<super-tab>` markers. Your routing solution might work but setting up everything in the `app-routing.module.ts` works perfectly fine aswell :)

Comment: @LittleOne Does it also work when the user click on the back button when you go to a children page? I know ionic to have bugs regarding this issue, if you declare page directly within the `app-routing.module.ts`. But if it's working for you then I'm glad :)

Comment: Yes the history doesn't get affected by the routing setup, I can go to previous page with no problem